How can we efficiently log request payloads and response bodies in Azure API Management without impacting performance?
I'm looking to log the entire request payload and response body for APIM requests for auditing and debugging purposes. If we can store to Azure Blob Storage, it would be great!
As of now, we have this logic baked into application code(NodeJS App) with a middleware layer to capture request and response and write to a file(using winston logger), then later on, these files are copied to Azure Blob Storage from the VM using Azure CLI with a scheduled cron.
I'm looking to see if there is a way to decouple the same from application and handle this at the APIM level.
I see a few options:

Use Azure Application Insights
Use Azure Event Hubs logger

Option 1 - Azure Application Insights
Using application insights, I see this can be with the following settings, there is a limitation of 8192 bytes though.

With this my worry is that it might affect the performance of the API.
Option 2 - Azure Event Hubs logger
Using the below policy, and following this guide
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="xrid" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.RequestId.ToString())</value>
        </set-header>
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="logger-id">
            @{
                return context.Request.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
            }
        </log-to-eventhub>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-header name="xrid" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.RequestId.ToString())</value>
        </set-header>
        <base />
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="logger-id">
        @{
            return context.Response.Body.As<string>(preserveContent: true);
        }
    </log-to-eventhub>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Event Hubs has a limitation of 200 Kilobytes


So you have 2 viable options, which you can start testing. If you are not happy with them, what exactly are you looking for, which these options don't provide? I suppose any additional logic has some (potentially marginal) impact on performance, but you'd need to create a prototype to see if you're comfortable with it. You could also add any custom logic to the API Management policies using C# to achieve what you need (save data to the blob storage), though it might have even greater impact on performance. Are you looking for that kind of answer?

I'm exploring alternative approaches to achieve the same outcome. Additionally, I'm interested in learning if any users have tested these options in real-world scenarios and what their successful experiences have been.

The best approach is to log the request body on the client side and the response body in the backend side if you do not do transformation on the APIM side.
Through application insights you can correlate the telemetries with each other

Both options will have impact on performance since request/response body would have to buffered in full before sent to EventHub/ApplicationInsights,. The third options is to send data to Azure Monitor and later to Log Analytics Workspace. All three have similar performance cost, but should show minimal impact if your payloads are smaller that 8 kilobytes.
